# Have someone a function for SQL Server that given a pattern and a value could return a normalized value

Tags: sql, function, design-patterns, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm programming a function in SQL 2008R2 that i could give it some parameters like a value varchar, a pattern varchar, a separator char and a filler also char. Then I would like to give the value '22687' with the patter '000.000.000.000', a separator '.' and the filler would be '0', then i would like to expect the function will return '000.000.022.687', does any one have a function already done that can do this?

Something like this:

```
DECLARE @valor VARCHAR(30)
DECLARE @formato VARCHAR(30)
DECLARE @separador CHAR(1) 
DECLARE @rellenarcon CHAR(1)

SELECT @valor       = '22959'
SELECT @formato     = '000.000.000.000'
SELECT @separador   = '.'
SELECT @rellenarcon = '0'

DECLARE @n  INTEGER
DECLARE @m  INTEGER
DECLARE @i  INTEGER
DECLARE @j  INTEGER

SELECT @n   = LEN(@formato)
SELECT @m   = LEN(@valor)
SELECT @i   = 1
SELECT @j   = 1

DECLARE @res2 varchar(30)

SELECT @res2 = ''
SELECT @valor = REVERSE(@valor)

WHILE @i<=@n
BEGIN
    if SUBSTRING(@formato,@i,1) <> @separador
    begin
        IF @j<=@m
        BEGIN
            SELECT @res2 = @res2 + SUBSTRING(@valor,@j,1)
            SELECT @i=@i+1
            SELECT @j=@j+1
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SELECT @res2 = @res2 + @rellenarcon
            SELECT @i=@i+1      
        END
    end
    else
    BEGIN
        SELECT @res2 = @res2 + @separador
        SELECT @i=@i+1
    END
END

print reverse(@res2)
```

Is a crossover code from java to tsql, the original code in java is:

```
    public static String formatear(String valor, String formato, char separator, 
        char fillWith, Map<Integer, String> params) {

    int n = formato.length() - 1;
    int m = valor.length() - 1;
    int i = n;
    int j = m;

    StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder(formato);

    for(; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(res.charAt(i) != separator) {
            if(j >= 0) {
                res.deleteCharAt(i);
                res.insert(i, valor.charAt(j--));
            } else {
                res.deleteCharAt(i);
                res.insert(i, fillWith);
            }
        }
    }
    if(params != null) {
        Set<Integer> keys = params.keySet();

        for(Integer key : keys) {
            i = key;
            res.deleteCharAt(i);
            res.insert(i, params.get(key));
        }
    }

    return res.toString();
}
```

Comment: What ends up consuming this data?  Typically I try to avoid formatting type stuff like this on the database side...

Comment: Would a reasonable description be: Given `@Pattern = '000.000.000.000'`, `@Fill = '0'` and `@Value = '22687'`, replace fill characters in `@Pattern` from right-to-left with characters from `@Value`?  The separator doesn't seem to matter.

Comment: its a code in java for a report in Birt that i need to do a crossover to sql @AbeMiessler

Comment: Can you format when the data is passed back to your java app then?

Comment: @AbeMiessler Maybe.. i'm just coding the sql side, the java app is another programmer, i'm going to ask for, because this things in sql could be expensive..

Comment: @AbeMiessler Maybe.. But the thing is that we are programming that the queries of the reports would be at a table, and then if we need to make a change to a report, we dont need to touch the reports, or any java code, just the query of the reports.. because is easier to take something from developmnet to production in sql than in java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following assumes well-formed inputs, e.g. the value is not longer than the pattern.

```
declare @Pattern as VarChar(64) = '000.000.000.000';
declare @Fill as Char = '0';
declare @Value as VarChar(64) = '22687';
declare @False as Bit = 0;
declare @True as Bit = 1;

with Gargoyle as (
  select @Pattern as Pattern, @Value as Value, Cast( '' as VarChar(64) ) as Buffer,
    case when Right( @Pattern, 1 ) = @Fill then @True else @False end as Fill
  union all
  select
    -- Always consume a character from the pattern.
    Left( Pattern, Len( Pattern ) - 1 ),
    -- Consume a character from the value if the pattern contains fill at the current position.
    case
      when Fill = @True and Value != '' then Left( Value, Len( Value ) - 1 )
      else Value end,
    -- Add the correct character to the buffer.
    Cast( case when Fill = @True and Value != '' then Right( Value, 1 ) else Right( Pattern, 1 ) end + Buffer as VarChar(64) ),
    -- Check the next pattern character for fill.
    case
      when Len( Pattern ) = 1 then @False
      when Substring( Pattern, Len( Pattern ) - 1, 1 ) = @Fill then @True
      else @False end
    from Gargoyle
    where Pattern != ''
  )
  select Buffer
    from Gargoyle
    where Pattern = '';
```

Or, as a function:

```
create function dbo.PatternFill( @Pattern as VarChar(64), @Fill as Char, @Value as VarChar(64) )
  returns VarChar(64)
  as
  begin
  declare @Buffer as VarChar(64) = ''
  declare @PatternChar as Char = Right( @Pattern, 1 )
  declare @ValueChar as Char = Right( @Value, 1 )
  while @Pattern != ''
    begin
    if @PatternChar = @Fill and @ValueChar != ''
      begin
      -- Replace a fill character with a value character.
      select @Buffer = @ValueChar + @Buffer
      if Len( @Value ) > 1
        select @Value = Left( @Value, Len( @Value ) - 1 ), @ValueChar = Right( @Value, 1 )
      else
        select @ValueChar = '', @Value = ''
      end
    else
      begin
      -- Copy the pattern character.
      select @Buffer = @PatternChar + @Buffer
      end
    if Len( @Pattern ) > 1
      select @Pattern = Left( @Pattern, Len( @Pattern ) - 1 ), @PatternChar = Right( @Pattern, 1 )
    else
      select @PatternChar = '', @Pattern = ''
    end
  return @Buffer
  end
go

declare @Result as VarChar(64)
declare @Count as Int = 1000000
declare @Start as DateTime = GetDate()
while @Count > 0
  select @Result = dbo.PatternFill( '000.000.000.000', '0', '22687' ), @Count = @Count - 1
select @Result as [Result], DateDiff( ms, @Start, GetDate() ) as [Total ms]
```

1,000,000 iterations on my notebook took 151,656ms, but it's busy BOINCing.  That's simple timing with no correction for the time consumed by an empty loop or calling an empty function.

Comment: I'm new to CTE, let me try to understand it.. lol, but it looks very impressive..

Comment: @Artemination - Just change the last part to `select * from Gargoyle` and you'll see what's happening.

Comment: I feel like the son of Flynn when he entered to the world of Tron..
thx u very much @HABO

Comment: answer accepted.. one more time thx u very much, i'm showing your code to my working team.. @HABO

Comment: however it is very slow.. 32 seconds with just 209.063 rows.. my ugly code made 2 or 3 seconds @HABO

Comment: @Artemination - As noted, it's the wrong tool.  Writing it as a `WHILE` loop in a user-defined function would probably perform better, but isn't as much fun.  Heading out to the Great Lakes Theater soon, but I can have a go at a function tonight.

Answer (score 0):

This query will do it:

```
;with cteZeroPadded(Num) as
(
    Select  Right('000000000000' + '22687', 12)
)
,cteSplit as
(
    Select  SUBSTRING(Num, 1, 3) Col1
            ,SUBSTRING(Num, 4, 3) Col2
            ,SUBSTRING(Num, 7, 3) Col3
            ,SUBSTRING(Num, 10, 3) Col4
    From    cteZeroPadded
)
Select  Col1 + '.' + Col2 + '.' + Col3 + '.' + Col4
From    cteSplit
```

Comment: That doesn't take `@Pattern` and `@Separator` as inputs.

Comment: Ah, indeed.  I got stuck on the "what if this" and failed the rest.  Not sure how to make that dynamic....

Answer (score 0):

In SQLServer2005+ you can use option with recursive [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
DECLARE @valor varchar(30) = '22959',
        @formato varchar(30) = '000000000000000',
        @text varchar(30),
        @result varchar(30) = N''

SET @text = REVERSE(RIGHT(@formato + @valor, 15))

;WITH cte AS
  (  
   SELECT 1 AS Number, SUBSTRING(@text, 1, 1) AS Num
   UNION ALL
   SELECT c.Number + 1,
          CASE WHEN c.Number IN(3, 7, 11) THEN '.' ELSE
          SUBSTRING(@text, CASE WHEN c.Number > 11 THEN c.Number - 2
                                WHEN c.Number > 7 THEN c.Number - 1
                                WHEN c.Number > 3 THEN c.Number
                                ELSE c.Number + 1
                           END, 1)
          END
   FROM cte c
   WHERE Number < LEN(@text)
   )   
   SELECT @result += c.Num
   FROM cte c
   ORDER BY Number DESC

SELECT @result
```

See demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/13394)